# "erroneous nesting of equation structures" , using \boxed, can't identify the problem

Tags: errors, amsmath, border

I want to create a frame around a piece of math notation, I'm using the \boxed{} command to do that:

```
$$
\boxed{
\begin{align*}
    &p = \text{Intervallverhältnis von 1 Cent} \\
    &2 = \text{Intervallverhältnis der reinen Oktave} \\ \\
    &p^{1200} = 2 \rightarrow p = \sqrt[1200]{2} 
\end{align*}
}
$$
```

It looks exactly how I want it to look like in the compiled pdf, but overleaf.com outputs the following error message: **Package amsmath error: erroneous nesting of equation structures**. Where is the problem and why does it still work? Are there other or better ways of achieving a black frame around a piece of math notation (or any kind of text) easily? I'm very much a beginner. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome! You should ***never*** use `$$` in LaTeX. Your problem can be solved with the `empheq` package.

Comment: (Off topic.)  Rather than using two double backslashes to insert a blank line, the option `\\[<dimen>]` can give more control.  But, when using `amsmath`, be sure to not insert a space between the `\\ ` and the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* use `$$` in LaTeX. Ever.

Anyway, it makes no sense to nest `align*` inside `\boxed`, because `align*` wants to be at the outer level (not even inside `equation`). You can look at the `empheq` package for more tricks, but in your case it suffices to do

```latex
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
  \begin{aligned}
    &p = \text{Intervallverhältnis von 1 Cent} \\
    &2 = \text{Intervallverhältnis der reinen Oktave} \\ \\
    &p^{1200} = 2 \rightarrow p = \sqrt[1200]{2} 
  \end{aligned}
}
\end{equation*}
```